# Meteor publications auth error or this.ready

Tags: meteor, coffeescript

In my publish methods should I be throwing an error if an unauthed user tries to subscribe to a publication or should i be returning `this.ready()` . (in coffeescript)

this:

```
Meteor.publish "secretInfo", ->
  return @error(new Meteor.Error(422, "Permission denied")) unless @userId

  return Secrets.find({})
```

or that:

```
Meteor.publish "secretInfo", ->
  return @ready() unless @userId

  return Secrets.find({})
```

Comment: You can do either but I'd recommend just `this.ready()` to avoid spurious errors in the UI. Presumably you're only subscribing to this publication if there's a user on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generally accepted solution is the latter:

```
return @ready() unless @userId
```

I try to avoid throwing errors in publications because the UI can (depending on how you implemented it) get stuck in a loading state unless your publishers eventually call `ready()` (either explicitly, or implicitly if you return a cursor or other valid value).

This is also pointed out in [the guide](http://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#publications):

> In the case of a logged-out user, we explicitly call this.ready(), which indicates to the subscription that we’ve sent all the data we are initially going to send (in this case none). It’s important to know that if you don’t return a cursor from the publication or call this.ready(), the user’s subscription will never become ready, and they will likely see a loading state forever.